# Get foreign address name using NETSTAT for established active TCP connections

Tags: powershell, netstat

I'm using NETSTAT command in PowerShell. I need to grab the list of foreign addresses which starts with XYZ name and are ESTABLISHED as state using TCP connections.

I stuck up at parsing because of the NETSTAT result as below.

`PS C:\Windows\system32> .\NETSTAT.EXE`

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    10.125.4.233:2310      157.05.39.133:2492     ESTABLISHED
```

I need the foreign address names not the remote address on the local host only.
Remote address doesn't show the FQDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $netstats = netstat -p TCP -f
 $data = $netstats[4..($netstats.count)] #The good info starts on index 4
 foreach($line in $data){
     $line = $line -split ' ' | ? {$_ -ne ''}
     $final += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'Proto'=$line[0];'LAddress'=$line[1];'FAddress'=$line[2];'State'=$line[3]})
 }
 $netstat_results = $final
 $netstat_results | ? {$_.state -eq 'ESTABLISHED'}
```

Now it should be easy getting the data you want after parsing the text that netstat returns.

Answer (score 1):

Running netstat /? yields, among other things:

-f            Displays Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN) for foreign
              addresses.

Parse, using New-PSObjectFromMatches:

```
netstat -f |
 new-psobjectfrommatches -pattern "(TCP|UDP)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+):(\S+)\s+(\S+)" -property $nul,TCP/UDP,LocalAddress,ForeignAddress,Protocol,State |
 where {(
         ($_.TCP/UDP -eq 'TCP') -and
         ($_.State -eq 'ESTABLISHED') -and
         ($_.ForeignAddress -like 'XYZ*')
        )} | select -ExpandProperty ForeignAddress
```

Comment: Coorect, it displays the list as i mentioned in my question. My question is different, how to parse to a variable for the list of foreign address names using powershell?

Comment: Ah.  Well, I use this:  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87  Parsing netstat output is in one of the examples.

Comment: No luck, I already tried this solution. But, I still go through again.

Comment: Update the answer with filter.

Comment: @mjolinor Good use of the ScriptCenter

Answer (score 1):

`+1` for @E.V.I.L. answer but it chokes the (slow) stream from `NetStat` due to the assignments (`$netstats` and `$final`).
To keep the pipeline streaming, it is better to avoid assignments, like:

```
netstat -p TCP -f | Select -Skip 4 | ForEach {
    $Properties = $_.Trim() -split '[\s]+'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Proto'= $Properties[0]
        'Local Address'= $Properties[1]
        'Foreign Address'= $Properties[2]
        'State'= $Properties[3]
    }
}
```

By adding e.g. `| Select -Expand 'Foreign Address'`, you just get the `Foreign Address`.