# How can I list all active and unique ips connections in a IIS server

Tags: powershell, iis, webserver, windows-server

I'm trying list all active connections in an IIS Server and i don´t know how to make this happen. I'm studying about some methods and trying to make a script in Powershell which extracts **a number of all connections in an specific port** (like 80 port) and **a number of unique connections in a specific port** (like 80 port).

I need this information because in some cases I have multiple access to this server based on the same IP, so I need filter this IPs access and look two numbers, one which show all active connections and another which show all unique connections.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Not entirely clear on the purpose here, is it for real-time monitoring/interaction? Or do you just need to audit/report on the client IPs after the fact?

Comment: I need real-time data to monitoring, or the closest possible. My ideia is receive a number to using that in a Zabbix service, to see in a Zabbix graph that numbers. I already have the Zabbix agent running in this server, i just need the data to see in the Zabbix service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Instead of using **netstat** commands, i´ve used the **Get-NetTCPConnection** resource, based on [these](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/22/use-powershell-to-identify-port-connections-in-windows-8/) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560531/get-foreign-address-name-using-netstat-for-established-active-tcp-connections).

So, i filtered all connections established in the port 80 and group by the foreign address (named as RemoteAddress).

- $count_unique_ips = Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80 -State
  Established | group RemoteAddress -NoElement
- $count_unique_ips.count

And based on [that link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/02/04/how-to-query-for-netstat-info-using-powershell/) I've solved the problem of list all connections in port 80.

- $c = netstat –aon | findstr ":80" | select-string “ESTABLISHED” ;
- $c.count

Answer (score 3):

You can list all active requests currently being *processed* by IIS with [`appcmd`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/930909):

```
appcmd list requests
```

The reason I deliberately use the word "process" above is that IIS doesn't actually handle/terminate HTTP connections - the low-level nitty-gritty work of handling connections is offloaded to the OS-level HTTP driver (`http.sys`).

It may preempt request processing if a request can be served directly from the kernel-cache, and such a request will never show up in the request list. To see active *connections* to the machine, you'll either have to break out `netstat`:

```
$Connections = netstat -aon |findstr ":80 "
```

or use .NET to [do something similar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$GlobalIPProperties = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
$Connections = $GlobalIPProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections() |Where-Object { $_.LocalEndpoint.Port -eq 80 }
```

On Windows 2012/8 or newer you can also use the [`Get-NetTCPConnection` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826153.aspx):

```
$Connections = Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80
```

The latter option is nice because you can easily interact with the objects in `$Connections` afterwards (ie. no string processing required). Such as grouping connections by IP for example:

```
# If using IPGlobalProperties
$DistinctIPCount = @($Connections |Group {$_.RemoteEndpoint.Address}).Count

# If using Get-NetTCPConnection
$DistinctIPCount = @($Connections |Group {$_.RemoteAddress}).Count
```

Comment: Thanks! I already using the netstat solution, but directly in the Zabbix agent configuration file. I want an solution via powershell to compare the results with the cmd option and choose the better between them. Do you have any ideias of to take a number of unique access (how many connections i have, regardless the number of IPs)?

Comment: Just count the lines returned by netstat?

Comment: Sorry, i got confused. To that, netstat works! But i still need the number of unique IPs connections. With netstats, i will have the total number of connections, but don´t the total of unique IPs connections, because if i have more than 2 access from the same IP, netstat just count all the lines, and i need just one occurrence in the counter.

Comment: @DaniloCardoso As mentioned above, you'll have to parse the string output from `netstat` manually if you wish to do that. I've added an example of how you could group/count connections by IP using .NET

Comment: So i can't just do that using the powershell commands? I don´t know the .NET language very well. I just want make this counts in powershell or cmd.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen i saw your addition to the post, and tried run here, but the codes return "1"  every time, even in a machine with multiple access. I will study that codes and made some changes to see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @DaniloCardoso try fiddling with it interactively to see what results you get from each command/statement